# why do I get this Error code 1146 on user definition?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a user on my database but I get the following Error

> Code: 1146. Table 'veicolo.VIN' doesn't exist

given the code :

```
create user User1 identified by '***';
grant select on table `Veicolo`.`VIN` to User1;
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: there is no table `VIN` in the database `veicolo`. So you can't grant any permissions on it ...

Comment: I mean, I've created the table and inserted data into it.. so I don't know why its not working

Comment: Well, the DBMS thinks otherwise. Check the spelling and maybe also the casing of database and table names in the db and in your query ...

Comment: I'm working on this db on my Mac, but previously I've never defined table's domains with ``. Could this be the problem?

Comment: If you are running on Linux, I bet your database is named `veicolo` and not `Veicolo`. I consider the lack of case in the error message to be a bug.